Are R7, R7s, and RSC base bulbs all the same thing?
I need to replace a halogen bulb from an outdoor floodlight.  The bulb has no markings of any kind, but I can tell that it's a T3 bulb shape.  From browsing at a local hardware store and looking online, the base seems to be either an R7, R7s, or RSC.  Are these actually different names for the same thing, or are they genuinely different — and if so, how do I find out which one I have?

Check the fixture, inside and out, there should be some information about the bulb type and wattage.

Take the bulb to the store and compare it to their stock.

Based on poking around 1000bulbs.com, I have come to the following, hopefully correct and useful, information:

R7 and R7s appear to be the same, with most references all over the internet showing only R7s as a current product type.
RSC is the base/socket for R7s bulbs.
R7s bulbs are mostly T3, but some are T4, T5, T8 and possibly others.
Both physical size (most T3 are ~ 4.7" long but others vary quite a bit) and amount of light vary significantly (1200 lumens to 27,000 lumens).
Power consumption varies roughly in proportion to light (lumens) within each type (halogen and LED). If you are going to replace halogen with LED then you need to look at lumens carefully based on a comparison with typical lumens of the previous bulb, which will often only list the power (Watts).

So most likely you have an "R7 == R7s == RSC" bulb but you need to determine the length (easy) and power/lumens (not necessarily as easy) to figure out what to replace it with. If you stick a T3 size / 1,000 Watt / 27,000 lumens bulb in a fixture that previously had a T3 / 100 Watt / 2,500 lumen bulb in it you will very likely destroy the fixture, and possibly everything around it.
